# Why i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }:

```
     btn = '<td class="sentBut"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="sentMail("'+tr[0]+'","'+tr[1]+'","'+tr[2]+'")">הזמן/י</button></td>';
```

What wrong here:

```
"'+tr[0]+'","'+tr[1]+'","'+tr[2]+'"
```

When remove this,it will work.

Thanks.

Comment: is tr a json array ?

Comment: Check the line below this one. You may have an extra `}` closing bracket. Hard to tell without what line the error is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following method. This will reduce your formatting issue.

```
var DataReplacement = function () 
{
    var s = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
        s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Use the function like below

```
var func = DataReplacement("sendEmail('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", tr[0], tr[1], tr[2]);
btn = '<td class="sentBut"> \
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" \
                 onClick="' + func + '"> yourText \
             </button> \
       </td>';
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are using single and double quotes inside of an html tag.  html has assigned specific meanings to these. For example, it is probably reading the onClick element like this:

```
onClick="sentMail("
```

because your double quote closes the opening quote. Fix it like this:

```
btn = '<td class="sentBut"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="sentMail(&#34;&#39;+tr[0]+&#39;&#34;,&#34;&#39;+tr[1]+&#39;&#34;,&#34;&#39;+tr[2]+&#39;&#34;)">הזמן/י</button></td>';
```

I know that seems a little crazy but those are html entities.

`&#39;` represents `'`

`&#34;` represents `"`

You can find all of the entities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML).

Comment: I believe the single quotes should be left unencoded as-per the logic of the code.

Comment: That looks crazy yea but i will use Mahedi Sabuj its look cleaner and i will adopt the way he use for next time. thanks for help.